# xml: get parent attribute from iterparse element

Tags: python, xml, numpy, xml-parsing

I have a large XML file with entries like

```
<data num_entries="1000000000">
   <item value="3.1324213213"></item>
   <item value="6.2432343213"></item>
   <!-- ... -->
</data>
```

(Actually, there are multiple `data` entries and they are deeper in the XML tree, but let's keep it simple.)

I would like to read this file with Python and put all `item`s into a numpy array. The file is so large that `ET.parse()` is not an option. To avoid choking on memory, I'm using `iterparse()` with `elem.clear()` like

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

items = []
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename):
    if elem.tag == 'item':
        items.append(float(elem.attrib['value']))
    elem.clear()
items = numpy.array(items)
```

This works, but is fairly slow since the `items` is allocated bit by bit. I would like to use the `num_entries` information of the surrounding `data` block to allocate the array first, i.e., something like

```
items = None
k = 0
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename):
    if elem.tag == 'item':
        if items is None:
            num_entries = get_num_entries_somehow()
            items = numpy.empty(num_entries)
        items[k] = float(elem.attrib['value'])
        k += 1
    elem.clear()
```

Unfortunately, `iterparse` gets to the parent element only *after* all `item`s have been iterated over.

How to access a parent attribute with `iterparse()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `num_entries` from the root of your xml by:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=filename)
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.attrib.get('num_entries'))
```

^ The above method will parse all tree at once, which is no good.

How about enabling `start` event?

```
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename, events=('start', 'end')):
    if elem.tag == 'data' and event == 'start':
        print(elem.attrib['num_entries'])
    if elem.tag == 'item' and event == 'start':
        items.append(float(elem.attrib['value']))
    elem.clear()
```

Comment: Not an option; the file is simply too large to parsing at once. I've clarified that in the OP.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Without `events=('start', 'end')`, the parser will only parse at the end, with it it will visit the entry both before and after. Just what I needed. Thank you!